# How to store the resulting formatted C string

Tags: c

This is a newbie question. To create a formatted C string, I use `printf`, like:

```
int n = 10;
printf("My number is %i", 10);
```

But, how about:

```
int n = 10
char *msg = "My number is %i", 10;
printf(msg);
```

How can I store the resulting formatted string in a variable? I want "My number is 10".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want to use [`snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf):

```
int n = 10;
char bla[32];   // Use an array which is large enough 
snprintf(bla, sizeof(bla), "My number is %i", n);
```

Do **not** use `sprintf()`; it is similar to `snprintf` but does not perform any buffer size checking so it is considered a security hole - of course you might always allocate enough memory but you might forget to it at some point and thus open a huge security hole.

If you want the function to allocate memory for you, you can use [`asprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf) instead:

```
int n = 10;
char *bla;
asprintf(&bla, "My number is %i", n);
// do something with bla
free(bla); // release the memory allocated by asprintf.
```

Comment: Note that the original post is unclear as to the required lifetime of the result ("How can I store the resulting formatted string in a variable").

Comment: Note that the `asprintf()` family of functions (`vasprintf()` being the other member) are not available everywhere.  They are available on Linux.  They probably are not available on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [sprintf()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf).

```
int ret;
int n=10;
char msg[50];  /* allocate some space for string */

/* Creates string like printf, but stores in msg */
ret = sprintf(msg,"My number is %i",n); 
printf(msg);
```

Comment: @Pablo sprintf() is not safe to use... :P

Answer (score 0):

Use `sprintf`:

```
int n=10
char *msg ="My number is %i";
char bla[32];   // Use an array which is large enough 
sprintf(bla, msg, n);
```

Comment: ops, I want only char *msg = "My number is 10".

Comment: @DavidGelhar well, it makes more sense. Updated my answer.

Comment: I'm sure he wants to use `snprintf` instead!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use something like sprintf
http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/11505-sprintf-tutorial-in-c/

it's used basically like this
(remember to malloc the msg variable first)

```
char* msg;
int ret = sprintf(msg,"My number is %i",10);
printf(msg);
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to allocate some memory for `msg` to point to before trying to copy data there.  Additionally, `snprintf` should almost always be preferred to it's dangerous cousin.

Comment: -1 The first argument to `printf()` should *always* be a literal format string (or a localized format string, or a string you've checked with `fmtcheck()`), i.e. you want `printf("%s",msg)`. The example given happens to be safe assuming the output of `%i` has no percents, but it's really bad style.