# get formatted string to a variable

Tags: c, string, printf

Is there any C function (or a way) to get a formatted string as a normal string?

For example:

```
printf("this is %s", "a message")
```

I want `printf()`s output `"this is a message"` in a `char*` variable. This should be simple but I'm not coming with something besides write it to a file and read it or concatenate as many times as needed.

So, is there a function or an easy way to put any formatted string into a single string variable in C?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store the resulting formatted C string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285596/how-to-store-the-resulting-formatted-c-string)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want either `sprintf` either `snprintf`:

### Usage

```
char str[128];

//sprintf(str, "hello %s", "world");
snprintf(str, 128, "hello %s",  "world");
```

Note that `snprintf` is safer since it will cut the string to appropriate length of encountered overflow.

### Documentation

- [`sprintf`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm)
- [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/)

---

### Why is `snprintf` safe

> `snprintf` writes output to the string `str`, under control of the format string format, that specifies how subsequent arguments are converted for output. It is similar to `sprintf(3)`, except that `size` specifies the maximum number of characters to produce. The trailing nul character is counted towards this limit, so you must allocate at least `size` characters for `str`.
>
> If `size` is zero, nothing is written and str may be null. Otherwise, output characters beyond the `n-1`st are discarded rather than being written to `str`, and a nul character is written at the end of the characters actually written to `str`. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behaviour is undefined.
>
> On success, returns the number of characters that would have been written had size been sufficiently large, not counting the terminating nul character. Thus, the nul-terminated output has been completely written if and only if the return value is nonnegative and less than size. On error, returns -1 (i.e. encoding error).

That is, `snprintf` protects programmers from buffer overruns, while `sprintf` doesn't.

Comment: "snprintf is safer" hmmmm, Without showing how to detect an incomplete write, `char buf[8]; snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "del %s", "c:\\junk.txt"); cmd(buf);` does not appear safe

Comment: All answers were good, but this one was brief, gave an example and linked to documentation. Thanks!

Comment: @chux, that's what the documentation is for. The only thing you need to do is to check the return value. "Notice that only when this returned value is non-negative and less than `n`, the string has been completely written."

Comment: This answer mentions "safer".  The documentation does not.  IMO "safer" here is unsupported without demonstrating proper usage - hence the comment.

Comment: @chux, no problem, I've added some explanation (which's bigger than the answer itself).

Answer (score 4):

Use `sprintf`:

```
sprintf( var, "this is %s", "a message" );
```

Note that `var` must be big enough to store the final string (including the string terminator).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the function you're lokng for is [`sprintf()`/`snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.5, *The `snprintf()` function*

> `int snprintf(char * restrict s, size_t n, const char * restrict format, ...);`
>
> The `snprintf` function is equivalent to `fprintf`, except that the output is written into
>   an array (specified by argument `s`) rather than to a stream.

It writes the formatted string into the array supplied as the first argument to it.

FWIW, these function do not handle the allocation (or checking, for that matter) of memory to the supplied buffer (array). While passing the array, you need to make sure the destination is long enough to hold the final result.